# What should I do to register clicks of my mouse and check the message via dmesg?

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

Here is the code of my very basic mouse driver so far

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include<linux/slab.h>
#include<linux/hid.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/usb.h>
#include<linux/input.h>


static int mouse_probe(struct usb_interface *interface, const struct usb_device_id *id)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "mouse (%04X:%04X) plugged\n", id->idVendor, id->idProduct);

    return 0;
}

static void mouse_disconnect(struct usb_interface *interface)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "mouse removed\n");
}

static struct usb_device_id mouse_table[] =
{
    { USB_DEVICE(0x1c4f, 0x0034) },
    {} /* Terminating entry */
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE (usb, mouse_table);

static struct usb_driver mouse_driver =
{
    .name = "usbMouse",
    .id_table = mouse_table,
    .probe = mouse_probe,
    .disconnect = mouse_disconnect,
};

static int __init mouse_init(void)
{
    return usb_register(&mouse_driver);
}

static void __exit mouse_exit(void)
{
    usb_deregister(&mouse_driver);
}

module_init(mouse_init);
module_exit(mouse_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Sidharth Kamboj");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Mouse driver");
```

How should I enable clicks for my mouse. I don't want any functionality rather I just want to register the clicks and then using the printk statement to add it to the kernel log and then I can check the log via dmesg.

Comment: As it is a USB mouse, you need to register a USB callback function(basically called a URB completion handler) to know that an event has happened in your usb device. I recommend you to go through the chapter on USB driver in LDD3

Comment: Never mind... I got 4 out of 10 :P